# LocationManager says I'm in Anttarctica

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

Obviously I'm not. Here is what I'm using to get location.

```
SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(getContext(),
                            new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {
                                    //use location.longitude and location.latitude
                                }
                            });
```

And here is the class I use above:

```
public class SingleShotLocationProvider {

public interface LocationCallback {
    void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
}

public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //If network is available
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }
                @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            }, null);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e("Location", "security exception");
        }
    }
    //If GPS is enabled
    else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        try {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }
                @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                @Override public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                @Override public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            }, null);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e("Location", "security exception");
        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "No network or GPS available. Try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


// consider returning Location instead of this dummy wrapper class
public static class GPSCoordinates {
    public float longitude = -1;
    public float latitude = -1;

    public GPSCoordinates(float lon, float lat) {
        longitude = lon;
        latitude = lat;
    }

    public GPSCoordinates(double lon, double lat) {
        longitude = (float) lon;
        latitude = (float) lat;
    }
}
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on what's going on here? Also, for some reason I can only get the location when GPS is enabled, and not over my network/wifi.If I try disabling GPS, both the if and elif conditions fail even though I have a good network connection. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the parameters in the incorrect order. On the constructor of `GPSCoordinates` you expect Longitude and Latitude, in this order. And when you create the `GPSCoordinates` you pass Latitude and Longitude, in the reversed order.

Change your `GPSCoordinates` to this:

```
public static class GPSCoordinates {
    public float longitude = -1;
    public float latitude = -1;

    public GPSCoordinates(float lat, float lon) {
        latitude = lat;
        longitude = lon;
    }

    public GPSCoordinates(double lat, double lon) {
        latitude = (float) lat;
        longitude = (float) lon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch! Guess I just needed a second set of eyes. Thanks!